# Better way to compose nested functions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, function-composition

Suppose I have two functions with the following types.

```hs
f :: (a, b) -> c
g :: (a, b, c) -> d
```

I can compose them as follows.

```js
function h(a, b) {
    const c = f(a, b);
    const d = g(a, b, c);
    return d;
}
```

Here, `h` is a composition of `g` and `f`. However, this looks a lot like imperative code with the constant declarations and the return statement. How can I compose any two such functions in a functional style?

Comment: Please use correct tags for your question. [python] tag isn't needed here

Comment: I would expect that the implementation of `g` would simply use `f`.  Instead of `g :: (a, b, d) --> <do something with a, b, and d>` it would look like `g :: (a, b) -> < do something with a, b, and f(a, b)>`

Answer (score 2):

You can define `h` in a single line as follows.

```js
const h = (a, b) => g(a, b, f(a, b));
```

Then you can generalize this composition for all such functions as follows.

```js
const ss = (g, f) => (a, b) => g(a, b, f(a, b));

const h = ss(g, f);
```

This is actually the same as the [S combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus) but extended to two inputs. Hence, the name `ss`.

Alternatively, we could generalize the S combinator to any number of inputs using the spread operator as Scott Sauyet suggested.

```js
const s = (g, f) => (...args) => g(...args, f(...args));

const h = s(g, f);
```

Personally, I'd stay away from polyvariadic functions.

By the way, you original example is not imperative even though it uses constant declarations.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem of how to combine two functions in a somewhat different way than by simple composition.  We can write combinators that do this for us.

In this case, we essentially want to use our initial `a` and `b` arguments in `f` to generate `d` and use `a`, `b`, and `d` in `g`.  We can write a function that combines arbitrary `f` and `g` to do this, keeping our original arguments and adding an additional one in the call to `g`.  Maybe we'd call it `addArg`:

```js
const addArg = (g, f) => (...args) => 
  g (...args, f (...args))
```

This version attempts to be a bit more generic; we don't handle only two parameters.  We can have any number of arguments to `f`, and we add one more to the call to `g`.

Here is a quick demo:

```js
const addArg = (g, f) => (...args) => 
  g (...args, f (...args))

const f = (a, b) => `f (${a}, ${b})`
const g = (a, b, d) => `g (${a}, ${b}, ${d})`

const h = addArg (g, f) 

console .log (h ('a', 'b'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything wrong with the previous answers but I wanted to add an alternative and also to warn you about combinators.

I feel uncomfortable with the use of custom combinators because the reader must look up their definition, which reduces the value of using them.

I am familiar with `lift2` and my first instinct would be to bend it to apply it to your pattern (your functions must be curried for it to work)

```
const lift2 = f => g => h => x => f (g (x)) (h (x));
const id = x => x;

const h = (a, b) => lift2 (g (a)) (id) (f (a)) (b);
```

So we're partially applying `f` and `g` with `a` and using `id` to store `b` until it's fed to `g`.

If you have trouble parsing the above, we can express `lift2` like so, to make it more clear what is happening:

```
const lift2 = ga => id => fa => b => ga (id (b)) (fa (b));
```

Honestly I would go for the first one-liner suggested by Aadit M Shah, or for the second one, but named `h`, to sort of convey "it's just the `h` you would expect, but with dependencies injected"... or your implementation. Yours even provides explanatory variable names. I mean why not!

Even known combinators sometimes only obfuscate intent. It all depends with whom you work. And that includes your future self ;)